# Rails - how to fetch from database the closest records according to date?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have in database stored records like this:

```
ID| date_column
1 | 2013-02-10 10:00:00
2 | 2013-02-10 11:00:00
3 | 2013-02-10 12:00:00
4 | 2013-02-10 13:00:00
5 | 2013-02-11 14:00:00
6 | 2013-02-11 22:00:00
```

I am trying to fetch 3 records, which are the closest ones to the today's date. For example, let's suppose today is `2013-02-10`, so I would need to fetch 3 records with today's date (`2013-02-10 11:00:00`, `2013-02-10 12:00:00`, `2013-02-10 13:00:00`), but for example if today is `2013-02-15`, I would need to get the closest 3 records, which are in this case `2013-02-10 13:00:00`, `2013-02-11 14:00:00` and `2013-02-11 22:00:00`?

Could you help me, please, how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Are you doing this through SQL or Active Record?

Comment: @JackMarchetti through ActiveRecord.

Comment: K. Check my answer below, that should solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ActiveRecord right?

This query will grab the three closest dates to "now" in the **past**:

```
time_to_check = Time.now
TableObjectName.where("date_column <= ?", time_to_check ).limit(3).order("date_column desc")
```

This query will grab the three closest dates to "now" in the **future**:

```
TableObjectName.where("date_column >= ?", time_to_check ).limit(3).order("date_column desc")
```

The only thing I can think of and this seems inefficient, but I can't think of a SQL way of doing this, is you now have two arrays basically with six records.

Three in the future (if there are any) 
Three in the past (if there are any).

I'd then loop through each and compare how much time has elapsed between each record from the `timeToCheck` variable.

Whichever three have the smallest amount of time difference,  Add those to your final array.

Comment: Hmm, but if today would be **2013-02-27** and in database would be `2013-02-26`, `2013-02-27`, `2013-02-28` and `2013-02-29`, then I would need to fetch 3 records that are the closest one to today's date... And the query wouldn't work for that

Comment: So you might have future dates in the database as well?

Comment: Yes, there are also the future dates.

Comment: Okay I've updated my answer. Not sure it's the most efficient way but I can't think of one query that will do this.

Comment: This is a bit complicated... probably I will have to do it in a similar way as you mentioned above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the 3 closes to a specific time, which I'm using noon on your target day. This will ensure today's results come ahead of any other day.

```
TableObjectName.all(order: "abs(timediff('2013-02-10 12:00:00', date_column))", limit: 3).
```

Comment: But this doesn't work on PostgreSQL database, or? Does `timediff`supported there?

Comment: Because when I try your sample, I get `PGError: ERROR:  function timediff(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist`

Comment: I don't have a PostgreSQL server handy, but I believe you can replace "timediff('2013-02-10 12:00:00', date_column)" with "'2013-02-10 12:00:00' - date_column" in PostgreSQL. (my example works in mysql)